# Реализация плавной сортировки на С++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Всем привет!
Вопрос будет достаточно коротким, т.к. много описывать тут нечего)

Нужна реализация **плавной сортировки** (smoothsort) на C++ (можно Java). Если на плюсах, желательно без использования указателей и побитовых операций.

Если-вдруг у кого-то есть время на это или есть уже готовая реализация, буду прыгать и визжать от радости.

Прошелестел весь *ГитХаб*, *западные сайты* в первую очередь, а после и *сайты стран СНГ*, потом *ютуб* и *Хабр* - сильно ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо в Гугле недолюбливают. Первая же ссылка ведёт на Википедию с объяснениями https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0?wprov=sfla1
Да и на Хабре есть https://habr.com/ru/company/edison/blog/496852/

Правда там нет реализации на плюсах... Но вот https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/smooth-sort/cpp/
А вот ещё http://cppalgo.blogspot.com/2010/10/smoothsort.html?m=1

Там правда есть битовые операции... Но тут такое дело... Я думаю, часть из них можно убрать, алгоритм будет не таким красивым, но нужно ли оно?
А видео на Ютубе вообще куча.

Comment: Я эти ссылки раз 10 просматривал. Со статьи на Хабре код на Пайтоне интерпретировал на С++, но программа возвращает исходный неотсортированный массив, пока не выяснил почему. Я же не зря в вопросе написал, что всё прошелестел) видео в ютубе, ту самую кучу, я уже просмотрел, концепция работы алгоритма мне понятна. Мне нужны не абстрактные схематические объяснения, а конкретная реализация на плюсах, вот и всё

Comment: И не те 4-5 реализаций с гитхаба, которые там есть, а с понятными названиями переменных и чтоб использовались максимально тупые и простые языковые средства, т.к. на плюсах я не писал, а появилась задача написать эту сортировку на них. Пробовал интерпретировать на Java, есть определённые результаты, но полноценно ещё не работает

Comment: Но спасибо за приведённые ссылки!)

Comment: С Вашего вопроса выглядит так, как будто ничего не нашли. Да, реализация тут не тривиальная, но почитайте оригинальное описание и назначение букв будет более понятным. А можете показать свой переведенный код, поищем в нем ошибки.